# Please explain the meaning of "appreciation" in the enclosed sentence

Tags: ambiguity, sentence-meaning, philosophy

> Reactions to German Idealism, especially those of the neo-Kantians, logical positivists and Bertrand Russell, were also instrumental in the founding of analytic philosophy, **which today reveals and benefits from an increasingly sophisticated appreciation of the European philosophical tradition.**

what does the bold part of that sentence exactly mean?

Comment: The OED says _appreciation_ means  "a. The action of estimating qualities or things; deliberate judgement. b. An expression (in speech or writing) of one's estimate of something: often implying a favourable estimate. c. Perception, recognition, intelligent notice; esp. perception of delicate impressions or distinctions." So admiration is usually part of it.

Comment: @JohnLawler, the intended sense here is more **c** than **b** or **a**. In any event, the way the word is used here is well within the core of the standard dictionary definition, and the OP hasn't explained what specifically was puzzling about it.

Answer (score 2):

In that context appreciate means to:

> understand (a situation) fully; grasp the full implications of

Comment: We could say that Analytic Philosophy **admires** European philosophy more and more.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, perhaps we could say that, but that's not what the quotes sentence, considered by itself, says. Grasping the full implications of something may lead us to admire it, but is not guaranteed to do so. The sentence is awkward anyway, because two very different points are squeezed into it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much ambiguity here.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appreciate

> transitive verb
> 1a: to grasp the nature, worth, quality, or significance of
> *appreciate the difference between right and wrong*
> b: to value or admire highly
> *She appreciates our work.*
> c: to judge with heightened perception or understanding : be fully aware of
> *must see it to appreciate it*
> d: to recognize with gratitude
> *I appreciate your kindness.*
> 2: to increase the value of

It's clearly not meaning 2.